# Why doesn't xargs on find work with a series of commands using pushd and popd to walk a directory subtree?

Tags: bash, automation, find, xargs

On a Linux [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 4 machine, I am trying to create a simple Bash command line to walk a directory structure below an arbitrary current directory and in each subdirectory touch a file, list the directory contents but pipe them to `/dev/null`, and remove the touched file.

The obscure point of this script is to tickle the underlying [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) client/server system to ensure the contents of each directory are reflecting a change made on a different machine which otherwise may take some time to propagate. I have found this workaround avoids the delay. Ignoring the merits of my reason for doing this, why doesn't my proposed Bash script work?

```
[CentosMachine] find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} pushd {}; touch xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ; popd
xargs: pushd: No such file or directory
bash: popd: directory stack empty
```

The `find` command is presently returning:

```
.
./dir
./emptyDir
./dirOfDir
./dirOfDir/ofDir
./dirOfDir/ofDir/Dir(empty)
```

At first I thought perhaps the `(` and `)` in one of the directory names might be the issue, but renaming that directory to be `./dirOfDir/ofDir/Dir_empty_` did not change the symptom.  I also tried looking at [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) output, but I did not see anything that helped, but I did see the directories being processed.

Here is a snippet of the end of the `strace` output with that directory renamed to use underscores instead of parentheses:

```
[...]
chdir("ofDir")                          = 0
lstat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("Dir_empty_", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("Dir_empty_", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
getdents64(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)   = 48
getdents64(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(4)                                = 0
chdir("Dir_empty_")                     = 0
lstat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("..")                             = 0
lstat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("..")                             = 0
lstat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("..")                             = 0
lstat64(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
fchdir(3)                               = 0
write(1, ".\0./dir\0./emptyDir\0./dirOfDir\0./"..., 75) = 75
exit_group(0)                      = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs` is a very useful tool for

1. executing commands with arguments taken from a dynamic source, and
2. minimizing the number of command invocations by building long command lines,
   with multiple arguments.

When you’re not doing #2 (i.e., executing one command per argument, as you are doing),
`xargs` isn’t quite so valuable; there are other ways to get the commands executed. 
In particular, if the source of the arguments is `find`, you can use the `-exec` option:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'pushd "{}" &> /dev/null; touch xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ; popd &> /dev/null'
```

But this answer, like yours, invokes a shell process for each directory. 
And each process has its own execution environment;
changing the working directory in a sub-process has no effect on the parent process. 
So you don’t need the `pushd` and `popd`. 
And you don’t need to specify `bash`; plain old `sh` will do. 
And, if you aren’t setting modification times, you don’t need `touch`;
a redirected null command will create a file. 
So we can reduce the above to:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}"; > xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ'
```

For your use case, this might not matter,
but in other situations you might want to perform the last three steps
only if the `cd` succeeds:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && { > xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ;}'
```

Note that you need to have whitespace after the `{` and a semicolon before the `}`.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer with this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6958689/115751).  Put the multiple commands into a form like this:

```
bash -c 'command1; command2; ...'
```

Which applied here gives:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'pushd "{}"; touch xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ; popd'
```

Note the addition of double quotes around the `pushd "{}"` so that the directory with `(` and `)` works properly.  Without that you get an error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `pushd ./dirOfDir/ofDir/Dir(empty) &> /dev/null; touch xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ; popd &> /dev/null'
```

However, the `pushed` and `popd` also need suppression to avoid output:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'pushd "{}" &> /dev/null; touch xYzZy.fixZ; ls &> /dev/null; rm -f xYzZy.fixZ; popd &> /dev/null'
```

Comment: You answered your question without answering your question. The short answer is that `xargs` can’t take a compound command; you need to wrap the compound command in a string and pass it to the shell.